# A ListView containing only images

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

how can i make a `listView` that only contains images and nothing else. i am new to the `listView` and all that `adapter` stuff. i succeed in making a `listView` containing text only but unable to do this with images.
this is what i have done so far.

My MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ImageView imageView;

int[] imageIds = {R.drawable.chrysanthemum, R.drawable.desert, R.drawable.hydrangeas, R.drawable.jellyfish};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<ImageView> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(this, R.layout.imageview, imageIds);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Main XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.danishrizvi.myapplication.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

ImageView Layout File

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

the error arises in this line `ArrayAdapter<ImageView> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ImageView>(this, R.layout.imageview, imageIds);` that is `Unable to Resolve Constructor`.
so  far what i have learned about my mistake by searching on the internet is that i might need a custom adapter or something similar to get my job done but was unable to know that how to implement and how that works.

Comment: can anybody share some readable content to understand the concept so far i have just managed to see examples and implementations.

Comment: you can use  [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) example to   [make list of image](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

Comment: just click on http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: ok thanks now i got it

Answer (score 0):

layout_adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_adapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

public ImageAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false);
    ImageView imgAdapter = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_adapter);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(arrayList.get(position)).into(imgAdapter);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Use this in activity like this,

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("image url");
arrayList.add("image url");
arrayList.add("image url");

ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

sample code is here:
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
Ii is showing row with image and text. So you can modified it according to your requirement.